# on/in its . . . pods

Tags: prepositions

I'm wondering if the boldfaced preposition in the following sentence is properly used.

> In November 2020, Virgin Hyperloop held the first passenger trials **on** its high speed vacuum tube transport **pods**. The transportation system uses magnetic levitation, or maglev, train technology.

Compare:

> Virgin Hyperloop says it made transportation history on Sunday when it tested human travel **in** a lightning-quick hyperloop **pod** for the first time.

Are both sentences correct in terms of preposition use? If so, why is "on" used in one but "in" in the other?

Comment: Because the first one is "trials on pods" and the second one is "travel in pods". Different words take different prepositions.

Comment: Why didn't the first one take "of"? "Trial of pods" seems more natural?

Answer (score 0):

> In November 2020, Virgin Hyperloop held the first passenger **trials** **on** its high speed vacuum tube transport pods....

> Virgin Hyperloop says it made transportation history on Sunday when it tested human **travel** **in** a lightning-quick hyperloop pod for the first time.

On the use of prepositions for  'trials', both **on** and **of** are acceptable.

> trial noun (TEST)
> C1 [ C or U ]
> a test, usually over a limited period of time, to discover how effective or suitable something or someone is:

> They're doing clinical trials **on** a new drug.

> Clinical trials **of** the new drug may take five years.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trial

There is no mention of 'trial in' in the passage, and hence there should be no debate; the passage mentions 'travel in'.  Debates on preparation choice for 'travel' is a separate matter.